# Computing the order of elements in a non abelian exterior square of a finite group

Tags: gr.group-theory, homotopy-theory, group-cohomology

If we have an explicit group $G$, and we pick two elements $g,h \in G$, could we find the order of the element $g \wedge h \in G \wedge G$?

The best thing I could find is Theorem 1.1 in Ellis' Book (http://link.springer.com/article/10.1023%2FA%3A1008652316165), which tells us that for any finite group $G$, $H_2(G)$ is a finite abelian group with exponent $e$ dividing the order of $G$.

Comment: How do you define $G\wedge G$? This is only standard in the case of abelian groups.

Comment: @YCor: It can be defined directly, or in terms of the nonabelian tensor square of a group. $G\otimes G$ is defined to be the group generated by all symbols $g\otimes h$, modulo the relations $gg'\otimes h = ({}^gg'\otimes {}^gh)(g\otimes h)$ and $g\otimes hh' = (g\otimes h)({}^hg\otimes {}^hh')$; $G\wedge G$ is then the quotient of $G\otimes G$ modulo the subgroup generated by all elements of the form $x\otimes x$. The two are closely connected to the Schur multiplier, $H_2$, and the commutator subgroup (there is an exact sequence $1\to H_2(G)\to G\wedge G\to [G,G]\to 1$, $g\wedge h\to [g,h]$.

Comment: Determining exact orders can be difficult, just as it is in any group given by generators and relations. It is not hard, usually, to give bounds (e.g., the order of $[g,h]$ in $G$ is a divisor of the order of $g\wedge h$), but unless one gets lucky, you will usually need more work to get the exact order (e.g., crossed-pairings)